# C++: How to cross-compile from Windows to Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I have a `C++` module on windows which I want to compile such that I get a dynamic library for linux `*.so`.

Does a cross-compiler exist that can help me out?

Comment: There might be available. Or you can build one. Or you can use a virtual machine to develop on Linux, or WLS (which is Linux running in Windows).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude • WSL "Windows Subsystem for Linux".

Comment: @Eljay One or the other... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several comments mentioned using Windows Subsystem for Linux. I would personally recommend this as it is far easier than trying to use a cross-compiler. It also comes with the added benefit that you can test your code in the same environment in which you compile it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about is a great resource for getting started with WSL.